# Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'.
}) : super(debugOwner: debugOwner, kind: kind);
^^^^

what I have done is update flutter and the dependencies, so as not to affect the time of compilation but it has not served much

```
class PhotoViewGestureRecognizer extends ScaleGestureRecognizer {


PhotoViewGestureRecognizer({
    this.hitDetector,
    Object? debugOwner,
    this.validateAxis,
    PointerDeviceKind? kind,
  }) : super(debugOwner: debugOwner, kind: kind);
  final HitCornersDetector? hitDetector;
  final Axis? validateAxis;

  Map<int, Offset> _pointerLocations = <int, Offset>{};

  Offset? _initialFocalPoint;
  Offset? _currentFocalPoint;

  bool ready = true;
```

Comment: Please post minimal code that can reproduce your problem.  The error message is clear: you're trying to invoke a superclass constructor with a named parameter that doesn't exist.  However, you haven't provided any clues to what that superclass is, so it's difficult to help you further.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation for the `ScaleGestureRecognizer` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ScaleGestureRecognizer/ScaleGestureRecognizer.html), you will see that it takes a `supportedDevices` named parameter that is a `Set<PointerDeviceKind>?`.  Therefore change `kind: kind` to `supportedDevices: kind != null ? {kind} : null`, or change your `PhotoViewGestureRecognizer` constructor to match `ScaleGestureRecognizer`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is in the definition of your `PhotoViewGestureRecognizer` class.

Your `PhotoViewGestureRecognizer` extends `ScaleGestureRecognizer` which has only [following](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ScaleGestureRecognizer-class.html) parameter that can we assigned to it. Which makes it clear that there is no named parameter `kind` in `ScaleGestureRecognizer` class.

**Possible solution:**

Ideally to fix after look on the data type variable `kind` in class `PhotoViewGestureRecognizer`.

I think you need to change the datatype from `PointerDeviceKind?` to `Set<PointerDeviceKind>?` which can we provided in the parameter `supportedDevices` of `ScaleGestureRecognizer` class in the super constructor.